# Router WiFi with solar energy

Tags: power, batteries, solar-cell

I want to create a backup system for my WiFi router ([photo](http://www.movistar.es/Microsites/ayuda/img/mitrastar.jpg)). I've purchased a solar panel (12V, 80W) and a battery (12V, 30Ah).  How long should my router last with a full battery?

Is it possible that with a 30Ah battery my router will last for 5 hours?

Comment: If you want somebody to do the math for you, you need to post the power rating (volts and amps, or watts) that's written somewhere on the router. Otherwise it's hard to know how much power it uses. My guess is not much though, so a 12V/30Ah battery ought to run it for a couple of days. Also, did you get somebody qualified to hook up the panel/battery for you?

Comment: What's the power or current rating on your router's current power supply?  That should provide a very crudely approximate upper bound on its needs.

Comment: For 5 hours, why do you want solar in the first place? If mains is available just use it to charge the battery. Any old UPS will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your router uses about 7W, as [measured](https://superuser.com/a/519806/314417) on a similar router.

If you don't consider inefficiencies then the math works like this:

Nominal battery power rating: \$12 V \times 30 Ah = 360 Wh\$

Dividing by your consumption: \$\frac{360 Wh}{7 W} = 51.4 hours = 2.1 days\$

But there *are* inefficiencies.  I assume you are connecting the battery to an inverter, then the inverter to the router's power supply.  Each of these conversions wastes energy.  If each conversion is 85% efficient, then you get a combined inefficiency of \$0.85 \times 0.85 = 0.7225\$.  This means that the entire system is 72.25% efficient.

So, multiplying it out: \$51.4 hours \times 0.7225 = 37.1 hours = 1.55 days.\$

This should be fairly realistic, although you may want to verify the values (router power, inverter inefficiency, etc)

Note that this figure is simply based on a full battery. It doesn't consider the amount of power provided by the panels. We would need a lot more information to try to predict the power generated by the solar panel.